# simplexml_load_string() StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: php, simplexml

I use simplexml_load_string() to parse a XML API response.

```
$lien = "http://myresponseurl";
$page = simplexml_load_string($this->get_data($lien));
```

Everythink is working good, except in this case:

```
<libdivision><1500 Poule H</libdivision>
```

Where the text to get back should be "<1500 Poule H" but, the "<" caractère is also in XML the symbol of an opening tag...

What should I do to get back "<1500 Poule H" without any errors ?

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 4: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <libdivision><1500 Poule G</libdivision>
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

```
<libdivision><1500 Poule H</libdivision>
```

This is invalid XML. The provider of the API should fix this, this is a clear bug in the API and a client is not responsible for working with malformed data. There are two options:

Wrap it in a CDATA field:

```
<libdivision><![CDATA[<1500 Poule H]]></libdivision>
```

Or encode the symbol:

```
<libdivision>&lt;1500 Poule H</libdivision>
```

Comment: I'm agree with you @DanFromGermany, but in waiting for a bugfix, I have to deal with it... :S There is nothing I can do for my part ?

Comment: @Macbernie You could try with a regex that replaces the `<` character when it does not have a following `>` before loading the data in simplexml but this is risky as it might not work all the time safely. The best thing is to wait and push the provider to fix this faster.

Comment: implement a proper stack machine that consumes the tokens and leaves everything left as plain text